# Класс двумерным массивом. Не все значения записываются.

Tags: массивы, классы, c++

Описываю класс так:

```
struct Ship_coor{
    float x;
    float y;
}coord_cell[10][10];
```

Заполняю массив так:

```
int j = 0;  
int i = 0;  
for(float m = 2.0f; m>=-2.5; m-=0.5f){  
    for(float n = -2.5f; n<=2.0f; n+=0.5f){  
        coord_cell[i][j].x = m;  
        coord_cell[i][j].y = n;  
        j++;  
    }  
    i++;
```

}

А попали только значения в coord_cell[0][0].
Почему это так происходит? И как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, почему только  в [0][0], но перед внутренним циклом обнуляйте j.

Comment: Блин, точно. Протупил жестко)) Вот из-за этого значения по одно строке. Спасибо)